# Translation models name in active admin

Tags: activeadmin

I'm looking to a way for translating model name in an active admin application.

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    models:
      project: Projet
    attributes:
      project: 
        title: Titre
```

It's work for the attribute but it didn't for the model name.  Any suggestion to fix it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with the `one` and `other` keys:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    models:
      project:
        one: Projet
        other: Projets
    attributes:
      project: 
        title: Titre
```